# Microsoft Teams Message extension without popup/extra params

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams, manifest.json

I want to have a message extension that simply sends the message text to the message handler. So when the user clicks the message extension from the (...) menu, that is it, no other input/step is necessary.

It appears that Microsoft forces you to have some additional parameters.

Is there a way to get around this and simply send the message content without additional parameters?

Comment: What do you mean by "simply sends the message text to the message handler." ? Do you want to call OnMessageActivityAsync method on click of the  message extension(...) from the menu ?

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT I want the user to select my chat extension, and that is it, no further input/action required from the user. No popups in the teams UI. It looks like Teams forces you to have some sort of extra parameter via user input, or a fetch task. I don't want to do any of that. 

Right now I have a placeholder ui and get the value via the `'composeExtension/submitAction` event. The bot associated with the extension has a message handler endpoint associated with it that receives all the callbacks, so whatever action text is in the body of that message, doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Subhasish-MSFT I was able to get the desired functionality by removing the `parameter` values, and setting `fetchTask` to false. So now when a user clicks on the message extension, there is no popup presented to the user.

```
"composeExtensions": [
    {
        "botId": "--Bot Id Here--",
        "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
        "commands": [
            {
                "id": "commandId",
                "type": "action",
                "title": "Command Title",
                "description": "",
                "initialRun": true,
                "fetchTask": false,
                "context": [
                    "message"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

Comment: Well this solution does work but the Teams manifest editor complains that `composeExtensions[0].commands[1].parameters | Array item count 0 is less than minimum count of 1.` which means the app cannot be published. However the app works  as expected. @Subhash does the same happen with you? @Adam what is your manifestVersion?

Comment: @AnkitSinha Can I ask how you solved the error? We're having the same error.

Comment: Just a heads up I think I used some workaround, but then when I went to submit the application to Microsoft they flagged it as an issue, and I had to conform to the requirements of having something shown.

Comment: @dylanvdb I didn't. The extension will work if sideloaded but cannot be published as the manifest is invalid.